# Session flash won't accept new CSS classes in Phalcon PHP

Tags: php, html, phalcon

I'm working on a simple Phalcon PHP project and I have a bit of a strange problem that I would like to know more about but I can't seem to locate the information to help me with my confusion.

```
$di->set('flash', function() {
    $flash = new \Phalcon\Flash\Session([
        'error' => 'alert alert-danger',
        'success' => 'alert alert-success',
        'notice' => 'alert alert-info',
    ]);

    return $flash;
});
```

Is producing `<div class="successMessage">The data saved with no errors.</div>` when I do the following from my controller.

```
if(empty($errors)){
        $this->view->disable();
        $this->flash->success('The data saved with no errors.');
        $this->response->redirect('dashboard/');
    }
```

I was hoping for `<div class="alert alert-success">The data saved with no errors.</div>` so for the moment I'm presuming I'm doing something wrong. My sessions seem to be fine so I've not explored that.

Looking around I found the following code which had been placed directly after the `$di->set('flash')`. It did kind of work when I tried it but it's generating html from my configuration file, which is not very MVC, and also means the html is produced outside of my of my container div making it reaaallly wiiiidddee.

```
if (!count($_GET))
{
    $di->get('flash')->error('Error');
    header("Location: ?t=1");
}else{
    $di->get('flash')->output();
}
```

See: https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/issues/2136

So if anyone knows what going on then please do enlighten me. The Phalcon guys are adamant in other forums and whatnot that there is no bug with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uhm. I guess you do do something wrong :)

First, the default DI already has `flashSession` service, just try to use that instead of `flash`, i.e., don't override it with `flash` (if you're using factory default).

Second, [documentation says](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/flash.html#implicit-flush-vs-session):

> The attribute ‘flashSession’ is how the flash was previously set into
>   the dependency injection container. You need to start the session
>   first to successfully use the flashSession messenger.

So make sure your session is started before your do anything, it actually seems the most likely reason as [here](https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/blob/master/ext/flash.c#L126-L129) you can see that default messages are used unless you pass the styles array. Meaning, that when you print, your `flash` service is initiated without that array…

I just tried it locally, works like a charm:

```
// In my di (not factory default di, just di)…
$di->set('flash', function() {
    $flash = new \Phalcon\Flash\Session([
        'error' => 'alert alert-danger',
        'success' => 'alert alert-success',
        'notice' => 'alert alert-info',
    ]);

    return $flash;
});

// In my index controller before redirection…
$this->flash->success('The data saved with no errors.');
$this->response->redirect('somewhere');
$this->view->disable();

// In somewhere redirected controller…
$this->flash->output();
die;

// In chrome output…
<div class="alert alert-success">The data saved with no errors.</div>
```

Comment: From your advice what I have done is add `$this->flash->output();` to my BaseController initialize function and now everything looks right. I was getting the wrong HTML via `{{ content() }}` in my volt file. Maybe a feature request is in order for Phalcon on that so doing the above isn't needed? Thanks for the answer; steep learning curve and all that :)

Comment: Hmmmm… The whole idea is to make this work in a view, though. I need to tweak a lot of stuff to test it, so I didn't bother. Won't you need at some point to customise where that output goes in html? If you post more details on how you get this from controller to a view and how you print it there, I might throw more ideas.

Comment: The problem with `$this->flash->output();` it doesn't return any value, it just `echo` stuff internally. Unless… you use `$this->flash->setImplicitFlush(false);` in which case it will return a `html` content for messages, that you can then pass to your view. Which is a little dirty anyway :)

Comment: Well now it's where I want it. I have never seen a way to customise the flash message and it's position in volt. There is only `<p><?php $this->flashSession->output() ?></p>` in the view as far as I know.

Comment: It's still coming via {{ content }} because it's after my <nav> bar.

Comment: If you use `flash` service, you probably should `<p><?php $this->flash->output() ?></p>` not `flashSession`. If you're using volt, you can do `<div id="messages">{{ flash.output() }}</div>`, at least that's [what the doc says](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/volt.html#inject-services-into-a-template).

Comment: Tried

{{ flash.output() }}
{{ flashsession.output() }}
<p><?php $this->flash->output() ?></p>

All those produced the wrong HTML. Reinstated '`$this->flash->output()` in the BaseController and moved `{{content()}}` to somewhere where I could see that I had dragged the flash to a new location and it appeared with the right style in the new location of `{{ content() }}`.

Comment: Also happens if you just echo "hello world" from the controller so I'm presuming it's losing it css style between hitting the controller and generating the view. Maybe the volt engine it to blame.